# Symbolic link to read a syfs directly

Tags: command-line, symbolic-link, cat

Is there a way to read a sysfs using a symbolic link

if I want to read a sysfs, for example, cat /sys/bus/usb/gps/time we usually type the cat followed by sysfs path and then enter

Is there a way to symbolick the command to some variable and read back I mean ln -s ( cat /sys/bus/usb/gps/time) sysread, so that when I type sysread it will print the cmd out which is same as alias I can only link the path but not with cat command so is there a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot "symlink a command", that is what `alias` is for:

```
alias sysread="cat /sys/bus/usb/gps/time"
```

Add the above line to your shell's startup (read `man $(basename "$SHELL")`file to make it "permanent", probably `$HOME/.bashrc`.